# how to make dictionary from multiple list containing stream of Reddit comments

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am extracting comments from reddit. I am trying to convert list of string to dictionary while fetching . List containing stream of statements i.e stream of comments.Cant post comments its too big; 
Keyuser is the username respectively. c1, c2, c3...c9 contains characters or statement. Like c1 is 1st comment made by username1 and  so on.(c1='hello how r u?')

i have used dictionary append, update function and dictionary comprehension but showing only one last comment made by each user.(
kindly please tell how to get all comments in dict

```
res={}  #empty dictionary  
all_comments=[]
name=[]
keyuser=['username1','username2','username3']
all_comments=[[user1],[user2],[user3]] #after fetching comments
user1=['c1','c2','c3']
user2=['c4','c5','c6']
user3=['c7','c8','c9']

#fetching comment like below
 name = keyuser
for i in range(len(name)):
    n=name[i]   
    for comment in  api.search_comments(author=name[i], limit=None):        
            all_comments.append(comment.body)       
    res = { k:v for k,v in zip(n, all_comments[0:])}
print (res)
```

OUTPUT should be like below 
print {username1:[[user1],username2:[user2],username:[user3]]}

or

print { username1:['c1','c2','c3'], username2:['c4','c5','c6'], username3:['c7','c8','c9'] }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the variable names before referencing them

```
key=['user1','user2','user3']
user1=['c1','c2','c3']
user2=['c1','c2','c3']
user3=['c1','c2','c3']
all_comments=[[user1],[user2],[user3]]
```

then use a dictionary comprehension:

```
res = { k:v for k,v in zip(key, all_comments)}
```

Note: python 3 now preserves the order of insertion in dictionaries (initially, when updated it's not guaranteed)
as you can see by printing it:

```
print(res)
```

produces

```
{'user1': [['c1', 'c2', 'c3']], 'user2': [['c1', 'c2', 'c3']], 'user3': [['c1', 'c2', 'c3']]}
```

Depending on your use, I see no value in nesting the values of the comments so I would do

```
all_comments=[user1, user2, user3]
```

which then produces

```
{'user1': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'], 'user2': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'], 'user3': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']}
```

Note: I guess you might want to store the user's comments and the users in a dynamic data structure (e.g. a list or a dict) instead of using distinct variables for each user.
That would allow you to accommodate any number of users instead of three only